# Display an element in JSP page using JSTL

Tags: jsp, jstl

I got a class `Student`, whose model attribute data is pulled from database and passed as 
    `map.put("student", studentDao.getStudents());`

I know how these element can be iterated over the JSP page, e.g.

```
                    <c:forEach var="student" items="${students}">
                    </c:forEach>
```

Is there a way where I can read only first element or any element of Student List object in JSP using JSTL tags?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get the first element ,

```
<c:out value="${student[0]}"/>
```

`[]` refers the indices. access it like the normal arraylist

You need not iterate the entire elements in the list to get the `nth` element.